# Adobe Acrobat Form - Using JS to Add multiple Dollar Amounts to Total

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have a simple form with 4 Text Boxes set up as Numeric Dollar Amounts.
(Default = $0.00 and text box allows for user input of actual dollar amount)

I am trying to get a 5th Text Box that is the Total Sum of the 4 Text Boxes above it to work, but JS is telling me that 'Price1' 'Price2' 'Price3' and 'Price4' are invalid:

ReferenceError: Price1 is not Defined
1:Field:Validate

etc.

How can I get this simple calculation to work?

I've tried the Calculate > Simple Field Notation of Price1 + Price2 + Price3 + Price4
but that does not work——I am assuming some kind of JS must be added to the Total text box and each of the Price Text Boxes as well.

Comment: Check the exact spelling of the field names; could it be that the field is called "Price 1"? You might also check whether omitting that field makes things work. Also check whether all four Price fields are formatted as numbers.

Comment: Perfect, the form calculations work now! I must have been getting the case value mixed up.